# G.711 c++ implementation

Tags: c++, c, audio, codec

Can you advise a G.711 audio codec implementation in C/C++ ?

I am going to use it in a proprietary software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the implementation [here](http://hazelware.luggle.com/tutorials/mulawcompression.html), its simple and fast.

Comment: Not a very useful long term answer, the link has gone dead!!

Comment: Try [this](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/research/projects/NetworkAudioLibrary/nal_spring/src/Codecs/g711.cpp) instead.

Answer (score 2):

[FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html) supports A-law and mu-law companders as far as I know.

Comment: FFmpeg is too "heavy" for my purposes. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Intel IPP libraries support G.711